# App keeps crashing with Android studio 4.0 profiler continuously

Tags: android, performance, android-studio-4.0, android-profiler

I am not able to profile app with android studio 4.0 profiler. The app is continuously crashing. Could you please help? The Heap size is 4096 MB and the utilization I see at the time of crash is close to 899 MB.

Comment: More information is needed. Please file a bug @ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533 and be sure to include both logcat logs, as well as Android Studio logs in the bug.